# printf flush problem

Tags: c

I am modifying a big C code. For test purposes I had to redirect stdout to a file. I used this code snipped for this purpose: `fp=freopen("OUT", "w" ,stdout)` Now all printf calls will write to fp. It is a big code so I do not want to search all of the exit points and close the file before each exit. What happens if do not close the file? Is there a way to make it autoflush each time I write something to the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setvbuf` is probably the way to go:

```
setvbuf (fp, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This will turn off buffering altogether. Just be prepared for the inevitable performance hit.

You also need to be aware that this will flush only at the runtime-library level in many systems, it will not necessarily cause a flush to the storage medium, as the UNIX `fsync(fileno(fp))` would try to do.

So, while it will be okay if your *program* crashes, it will not help if the whole OS falls in a screaming heap. But then you probably have bigger problems than losing a little bit of output :-)

---

But, unless your program *is* crashing, you probably shouldn't worry about it. ISO C99 says, in part, that one of the actions of `exit()`, and hence returning from `main()`, is:

> Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are closed, ...

So your data will be output regardless in that case.

Comment: It's also possible to set line-buffering, which is the default on stdout.

Comment: @Jan: "default on stdout" _if it can be determined to refer to an interactive device._

Comment: @Jan: Question: does `freopen` alter the buffering mode? If so, the "default on `stdout`" won't matter much.

Comment: Actually I believe it's a bit different than that: `stdout` should not be fully-buffered by default unless it can be determined *not to refer* to an interactive device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use [`setvbuf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) with `_IONBF`:

```
setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
```

Comment: paxdiablo's answer is much better because it explains how to do this, but also why it's unnecessary/useless.

Comment: @R..: Agree. My response was my little contribution to Fastest Gun in the West, as usual. When I saw paxdiablo's improvements, I figured I may as well give up. ;-)